# Flascc/Alchemy/Emscripten analog for IL/.NET?

Tags: javascript, c++, .net, c, actionscript-3

So there is [Flascc](http://gaming.adobe.com/technologies/flascc/)/[Alchemy](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/alchemy/#Windows), [Emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten) tha turn C/C++ into AS3 and JS. AS3 and JS are grate but is there any such nice compiler for IL/.NET (llvm-to-.net)?

Comment: Why doesn't Managed C++ work for you?

Comment: I asked this same question a while back [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760167/c-to-bytecode-compiler-for-clr) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760549/c-to-bytecode-compiler-for-silverlight-clr)